# whatwg-fetch SyntaxError: Unexpected string

Tags: javascript

I want to use this fetch polyfil so that i can do integration tests on my sdk using jest.

However when i run my tests i get.

```
 /jest.setup.js:2
    import 'whatwg-fetch';
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    SyntaxError: Unexpected string
```

**jest.config.js**

```
// File jest.config.js
module.exports = {
    "verbose": true,
    setupFiles: ['./jest.setup.js'],
};
```

**jest.setup.js**

```
// File jest.setup.js
import 'whatwg-fetch';
```

**package.json**

```
    "scripts": {
        "test": "jest"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.2.2",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.2.3",
        "babel-jest": "^23.6.0",
        "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
        "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
        "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.6.0",
        "jest": "^23.6.0",
        "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.1",
        "webpack": "^4.28.4",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.2.1",
        "whatwg-fetch": "^3.0.0"
    }
```

Comment: which version of Node are you using? `import` is not supported in all of them... `const { fetchPolyfill } = require('whatwg-fetch')` should work

Comment: Looks like you haven't configured babel to transpile your `jest.setup.js` file